# C# Datagridview Run "SELECT Raw_Cab.CAB, Count(*) AS Total"

Tags: c#, select, datagrid, filter, count

I want to run a query over a datagridview1 who is filled with this data:

> **Nr  Name    Cost**
>
> 125   NAME1   1
>
> 126   NAME1   2
>
> 127   NAME1   1
>
> 128   NAME2   1
>
> 129   NAME2   2
>
> 130   NAME4   1
>
> 131   NAME1   1

The data is added programmatically from a external txt source.

Normally if you use a query and a database the text would be :

`SELECT Raw_Cab.Name, Count(*) AS Total FROM Raw_Cab GROUP BY Raw_Cab.Name;`

And the result would be

> **CAB  Total**
>
> ```
> NAME1 5
>
> NAME2 3
>
> NAME4 1
> ```

Is there a way to get the same result but then directly from a datagrid into an object or another datagrid?

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the goal, but if I understand correctly, you would like to pass a filter expression on the datagrid? You can do it on the grid view, using this code:

```
(dataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Total < '{0}'", 5);
```

More on it can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I solved by installing Xammp and run the mysql query's on it
Thanks to all